# Merge two layers with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to merge two layers with Keras using concatenate. I am using tensorflow 1.12 built-in keras functions. When running the following code I get the error:

> ValueError: A `Dot` layer should be called on a list of 2 inputs.

```
branch1 = Sequential()
branch1.add(Dense(10))

branch2 = Sequential()
branch2.add(Dense(10))


model = Sequential()
dot_product = dot([branch1, branch2], axes=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing two models to your Dot layer instead of two tensors. You can use the functional API instead to define a model with two inputs and then take the dot product:

```
input_1 = Input(input_shape)
input_2 = Input(input_shape)

branch_1 = Dense(10)(input_1)
branch_2 = Dense(10)(input_2)

dot_product = Dot(axes=1)([branch_1, branch_2])

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=dot_product)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AnnaKrogager ! Is it still possible to use the Sequencial API to accomplish this? What is the purpose of the dot() function then? I apologize if this questions do not make sense, I am new to this...

Comment: By definition, the Sequential model is a linear stack of layers, so for branching you have to use functional API (which is not complicated, as you can see). The `dot` function is just an interface to the `Dot` layer.

Comment: I tried @AnnaKrogager solution but I am getting the following error in the last line: TypeError: "_init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputs'" and this is my import: "from tensorflow.keras.models import Model" so I removed the "keras.models." in the last line.

Comment: I noticed a type in my answer. It should be `outputs` instead of `output` at the last line. I will update my answer with the correct code.